# Typescript Generic type to value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an example function like this:

```js
type U = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

const bar = <V extends U>(value: V) => {
  console.log(value)
}

const foo = <K extends U>() => {
  const value // value of K
  console.log(value)
}
```

`bar` is OK, but I wonder if we could do something like `foo` in TypeScript.

Comment: the generic in foo is not relevant because no matter what K is, it doesn't affect the function foo in any way. plus ts will strip types at compile time, so you can't do this.

Comment: Yeahhhhh, I'm stupid.
Appreciate your comment.